# endcsname error with \tkzMarkRightAngle

Tags: tkz-euclide

I am not sure why I am getting this `Missing \endcsname inserted` error when I use `\tkzMarkRightAngle`. I used my code entirely in `tkz-euclide`. What I am trying to achieve is right angle marks on both side of the bisector on each opposite side of the equilateral triangle.

Like this:

[image: example]

While I have this:

[image: myoutput]

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,3/0/B}
    \tkzDefEquilateral(A,B)
    \tkzGetPoint{C}
    \tkzDefTriangleCenter[centroid](A,B,C)\tkzGetPoint{I}
    \tkzDrawPolygon[color=blue](A,B,C)
    \tkzDefPointBy[projection=onto A--C](B)
    \tkzGetPoint{Ib}
    \tkzDefPointBy[projection=onto B--C](A)
    \tkzGetPoint{Ia}
    \tkzDefPointBy[projection=onto A--B](C)
    \tkzGetPoint{Ic}
    \tkzDrawSegment[red](B,Ib)
    \tkzLabelSegment[red,pos=0.8](B,Ib){$1$}
    \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|,size=2pt,pos=0.8,red](B,Ib)
    \tkzDrawSegment[red](A,Ia)
    \tkzLabelSegment[red,pos=0.8](A,Ia){$1$}
    \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|,size=2pt,pos=0.8,red](A,Ia)
    \tkzDrawSegment[red](C,Ic)
    \tkzLabelSegment[red,pos=0.8](C,Ic){$1$}
    \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|,size=2pt,pos=0.8,red](C,Ic)
    \tkzDrawCircle[thick,violet](I,Ib)
    \tkzMarkAngle[mark=none,size=15pt,red](A,I,Ic)
    \tkzLabelAngle[red,dist=0.3](A,I,Ic){$\frac{\pi}{3}$}
    %\tkzMarkRightAngle[red,size=1pt](A,Ia,C)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I try `\tkzMarkAngle(A,Ia,C)` I get “dimension too large”, which might explain the issue.

Comment: I tried that too. I do also get `Dimension too large`. Could there be a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `size` can't be specified as a length, it's just a number. Haven't looked up what the number means, but

```
\tkzMarkRightAngle[red,size=0.2](A,Ia,C)
```

works.

Comment: `\tkzMarkRightAngle(A,Ia,C)` worked fine for me though, no overly large dimensions, so perhaps something else is up ..

Comment: It's weird how `tkzMarkAngle` has `size` with dimensions but `tkzMarkRightAngle` doesn’t.

Comment: @MarkA.Bromuela that package is good just for beginners, but not so well-programmed (many minor mistakes). Hope it is better in next versions.

Comment: @SolidMark Yes you are right. JI have been working for several months on the new version and it is now corrected.

Comment: @BlackMild Yes you are right ! There a lot minor mistakes but I try to correct as much as possible when I have time.